# How\where to use SaveStringToFile() in my inno setup file

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm not that familiar with inno (or pascal scripting), but I am assuming what I want to do is pretty simple.

I want to edit a particular text file at the very beginning of the install. Is there a place in the [Code] section were I could just plug this in so that it does this first and then just continues as usual? I'm not really asking for a code example because I think I could figure that out, but I just wanted to know where to put the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The install is done between the `CurStepChanged(ssInstall)` and `CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)` event function calls. ssInstall is the correct point to run code for the beginning of the install.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I didn't check back sooner. So I should add a CurStepChanged procedure then (as there is not one already).